# what does de slope of a band means in a band diagram?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I see a direct transition at the K point, but what can i read from the Gamma-
A horizontal lines in this diagram?

In a general question: what does de slope of a band means?

[image: I have this band diagram]

Comment: Welcome in Physics SE.  Your question is tagged solid-state and electrons, but consider to add one or two sentences to clarify the topic. It will serve also to other people later...

Comment: It's the Fermi velocity (times $\hbar$).  Google should take you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope gives the group velocity of the electrons with a given k vector:
$$v_{group}(k)=\frac{\text{d}E(k)}{\text{d}k}$$

The group velocity in the $\Gamma$-A direction is thus almost zero for these bands. This indicates that the electrons are strongly localized in that direction. This makes sense, since molybdenum disulfide is a layered material, with only little interaction between the layers. If the bands were truly flat, this would mean there would be no coupling at all between the layers.

However, the bands in you graph are not completely flat. The band near the Fermi level for instance slowly increases. This indicates that there is at least some coupling, which makes sense, because otherwise the material would fall apart.